# Can't login to the microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-account

So I can't login to any microsoft account in windows phone 8.1 plus facebook, twitter, gmail(on outlook) say having trouble getting data. Internet works fine on internet explorer and I can login to my live account on the browser. my phone is lumia 520.

Answer (score 2):

Check your date and time settings, they have to be right for the region you're in. Also try a doing a soft reset.
Also sometimes this is just an issue with Microsoft services, might resolve itself eventually.